# How to get the percentage of the column 'marks' in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This is my table:

[image: this my table]

I try this code:

```
SELECT student_name, (marks)*100/(SELECT SUM(marks) as 'totalmarks') 
from tbl_marks 
GROUP BY student_name
```

and I get this result:

[image: this is the result that I got]

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
select m.student_name, m.marks * 100 / t.marks as percent_overall
from (select student_name, sum(marks) marks from tbl_marks group by student_name) m
cross join (select sum(marks) marks from tbl_marks) t
```

This can also be expressed with window functions, like:

```
select 
    student_name,
    sum(marks) * 100 / (sum(sum(marks)) over()) percent_overall
from tbl_marks
group by student_name
```